# How to store a structure info in tabular view - IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have general question related to`UITableview` in IOS. I have a `UITableview` which I is used to store contact information. Till now I have inserted an`NSArray` object into `UITableview` to show contacts name. Is it possible to add full contact related structure into UITableview so that I can do action based on the contacts selected. I want to differentiate  between the different kind of contacts added in table view. Using `NSArray` I have only strings that will be not enough to differentiate. Is there any way?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing multiple `NSDictionary` in a `NSArray` is often a good solution. Then you'll have the tabel position corresponding to `NSArray` index and those key / value combinations you need at your disposal.

Comment: Hi Marcus,  As I am new to IOS, I don't have idea about NSDictionary, I will check how it is working, by the way NSdictionary is the only solution?

Comment: You could use Core data but that is far more advanced and will be a lot more to understand.